# WebGL & Three.js - two renderers, no shadows in FF in second one

Tags: firefox, three.js, webgl, shadow

we have a setup with two WebGLRenderers (using the clone of the same scene, to avoid issues). Same scene, same lights, same camera. Second renderer is used for snapshoting on demand (to avoid problems with aliasing of RT rendering, etc.).

All this works like a charm in Chrome but in Firefox (35.0.1) we are missing shadows completely (only one shadow caster in scene, Spotlight)... Is this a known issue/limitation of FF (windows7/8/8.1)?

Any insight greatly appreciated.

```
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        alpha : false,
        antialias : true,
        preserveDrawingBuffer : true // required to support .toDataURL()
    });

//shadows
    renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
    renderer.physicallyBasedShading = true;
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

renderer.render(snapshot.scene, snapshot.camera);

var data = renderer.domElement.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

I forgot to mention directly in the post that **shadows are missing only in the second webGLRenderer instance** (snapshot one).

What should I debug in FF (some webgl implemetation structs?). When comparing Chrome and FF status of threejs scene/renderer/camera/lights all seems to be ok and the same between browsers.

Comment: You should post the project online for people to test.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not at liberty of sharing the code of project, just wanted to see if anybody has seen something similar happening lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is problem with lending on floating point textures. See http://3dwayfinder.com/webgl-broken-in-firefox-35-0-1-for-windows/

Comment: thanks for the link, may be linked but as we are missing shadows only in one of the renderers it's probably not directly connected :(

Comment: wow, you're actually right, downgrading to FF 34.0.5 everything works fine, thanks for the tip! (sorry, cannot voteup with low reputation :( )